# Should I expect to find gaps or open spaces in custom cabinets?

Tags: cabinets, custom

Contractor installed unassembled custom cabinets in kitchen.  There are open spaces at every corner that you can look underneath and see to the ceiling.   We are being told this is customary practice?   Is it?

Comment: Pictures will help to tell more, but usually cabinets do not have gaps/openings, unless for a purpose.  Even the cheap ones are usually made to be tight together when new.

Comment: Where are these open spaces at the corner? If they're at the back, then that's to be expected because the _face_ of the cabinets meet up, but the face frames are usually wider than the rest of the cabinet carcass. If they're at the front, then it may be that there are filler strips that should be put in place. If there are uneven gaps, then the cabinets weren't leveled. We'll need more details (and the above requested pictures) to help you decide which is the case here.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are we talking gaps in where the parts of the cabinet boxes meet, or gaps around the outside of the boxes?

Comment: Without pictures it is hard to understand what you're talking about? It is possible that openings in the sides of the cabinets where they meet the walls are getting filled with scribe pieces and the top may be getting a valance? Perhaps there is a soffit above the cabinets?

Answer (score 1):

I have assembled a number of cabinets for use in the homes I renovate. I can tell you with certainty that there should not be any gaps between bottoms, sides or tops.

It is easy to assemble cabinets poorly. To do it properly takes care.
My guess is the contractor wanted to just get it done quickly.

All that said; If what you are referring to is the open triangle space that is only between the corner wall and the back of a corner cabinet, that is common and is built into the design of the cabinet and not related to quality of assembly or install.